# Android MVVM ROOM Single Sources of Truth Question

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

About Single Sources of Truth Google document said:

> Using this model, the database serves as the single source of truth, and other parts of the app access it using our UserRepository. Regardless of whether you use a disk cache, we recommend that your repository designate a data source as the single source of truth for the rest of your app

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide?gclid=CjwKCAjwo4mIBhBsEiwAKgzXOH1Pq--Ws1PLzUiSP4RmDE6ByKfEi6mdXu5g86btqveIdJvvrgYuxBoCz8wQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#connect-viewmodel-repository

According to the document I save all data when I fected data from remote server and I only get data from room When I need to use in acitivty(In fact I collect flow which is defined in viewmodel).

It seems so good! It avoids the different data sources mix up together! But actually I found some strange question gradually:

In my App, I have a list that the server may change it(Because we have data manager website that admin can update or delete data). So in order to get the newest list data from server, I must clear all data stored in room and fect data again from remote server. This operation seems redundant: "why could I get data directly from remote server", I mean, I only get data from remote source is also a single sources truth. And also it cause a promble: my app will flash a moment because clear data make list empty and fect data from server make list full!

The most important thing is that it seems like the local data is not necessary because I must stay the newest list from remote server.
Some people may say that save data into room can make us app available offlice. I agree that, But in this place, my item of list is represent a image url, and after click the item, the app will jump to a new activity and display a ImageView base on the url we get from the list. If app offlice, the ImageView couldn't load the url also.

I am so confused I couldn't load all image url(use base64-url to avoid load invalid) in a moment also, because the data is so much. And if I say I need a search function in this list and I need load so much unbelievable data into my room, It seems so unreal and event fantasy!

In brief：

Room is a nessary? Couldnt just fect data from remote?

If room is nessary, how to solve problem I met, do my incorrect useage cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @psycongroo as I Understood your problem, and I want to share my experience:

1. You can handle any error with loading URL with placeholder I mean if you got an error with no Internet connection user will see placeholder, but in general libs like Picasso or Glide can cache images when it`s load one time, so the user will see the Image.
2. The question about why we need to use room instead of fetch data from remote directly. So from your question I don`t understand why you need to drop your local changes even they are completely new, user can have a low internet connection so he will see an empty list instead of previous data with for example progress indicator. And also if the user doesn't have the internet at all you can show some dialog to explain what the problem but old data is still present. If you are using, for example, RecyclerView you can update data with Paging 3 from google, and they update the only necessary items from your list.
   P.S. let me know if that help, or you have another question.